# rvest: html_table() only picks up header row. Table has 0 rows

Tags: r, rvest

I'm learning how to webscrape with `rvest` and I'm running into some issues. Specifically, the code is only picking up the header-row.

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)

URL1 <- "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-salary-changes?date=2017-11-25"
df <- URL1 %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#stat-table") %>% html_table()
```

Calling `df` results in a data.frame with 7 columns and 0 rows. I installed inspector gadget, and even that is telling me that `id = #stat-table` is correct. What is unique about this website that it doesn't want to pickup the table data?

As a separate question, if I "View Page Source", I can see all the data on the page and I wouldn't have to use `RSelenium` to flip through DK, FD, or yahoo salaries. It looks like there are keys that would be easy to find (e.g. find "FD" > find all "player name:" and pick up characters after, etc), but I don't know of a library/process that handles the page source. Are there any resources for this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is due to that site having the data in embedded javascript on that page and rendering it after page load.

Comment: @hrbrmstr ah I see. So to my last paragraph, is there a package or methodology that allows you to pull from the page source and parse? Because it looks like all the data is there behind the scenes. I remember pulling from the page source with Python/beautiful-soup a while back, but I prefer to use R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could -- in theory -- extract the data from the `<script>` tag and then process it with `V8` but this is also pretty easy to do with `splashr` or `seleniumPipes`. I wrote `splashr` so I'll show that:

```
library(splashr)
library(rvest)

start_splash()

pg <- render_html(url="https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-salary-changes?date=2017-11-25")

html_node(pg, "table#stat-table") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() 
## # A tibble: 256 x 7
##    Position          Player Salary         Change `Proj Fantasy Pts` `Avg Fantasy Pts`   Diff
##       <chr>           <chr>  <chr>          <chr>              <dbl>             <chr>  <chr>
##  1       PF      Thon Maker $3,900  +$600 (18.2%)              12.88             13.24  -0.36
##  2       PG DeAndre Liggins $3,500  +$500 (16.7%)               9.68              7.80  +1.88
##  3       PG   Elfrid Payton $6,400  +$700 (12.3%)              32.77             28.63  +4.14
##  4        C   Jahlil Okafor $3,000 -$400 (-11.8%)               1.71             12.63 -10.92
##  5       PF    John Collins $5,200   +$400 (8.3%)              29.65             24.03  +5.63
##  6       SG     Buddy Hield $4,600  -$400 (-8.0%)              17.96             21.84  -3.88
##  7       SF    Aaron Gordon $7,000   +$500 (7.7%)              32.49             36.91  -4.42
##  8       PG    Kemba Walker $7,600  -$600 (-7.3%)              36.27             38.29  -2.02
##  9       PG    Lou Williams $6,600  -$500 (-7.0%)              34.28             30.09  +4.19
## 10       PG       Raul Neto $3,200   +$200 (6.7%)               6.81             10.57  -3.76
## # ... with 246 more rows

killall_splash()
```

BeautifulSoup won't read this data either. Well, you can target the `<script>` tag that has it in JS form and use a similar V8-engine on Python as well, but it's not going to be able to do this any easier than `rvest`.

Further expansion on ^^:

Most scraping guides tell you to do "Inspect Element" to eventually find the XPath or CSS selector to target. Inspecting on a random row of that table shows:

[image]

For "normal" sites, that generally works.

Sites with JS-rendered XHR requests (or on-page JS+data) will look like ^^ but your targeting won't work b/c `read_html()` (and the BeautifulSoup equiv) can't render JavaScript on pages without the help of some rendering engine. You can try to tell if this is happening by doing a View Source along with the element inspection. Here's the View Source for that site cropped to the very long lines of data + JS + HTML that eventually make the table:

[image]

I've posted numerous SO answers for how to target those `<script>` tags and use `V8`. Using `splashr` or `decapitated` is just easier (if they're installed and working).

If you don't want to deal with Docker and use a recent version of Chrome, you can also follow the guidance [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) to get headless working and do:

```
res <- system2("chrome", c("--headless", "--dump-dom", "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-salary-changes?date=2017-11-25"), stdout=TRUE)
```

`res` then becomes plain HTML that you can read in with `rvest` and scrape away.

A package-in-development —- `decapitated` -- makes ^^ a bit less ugly:

```
install_github("hrbrmstr/decapitated")
library(decapitated)
library(rvest)

chrome_version()
## Google Chrome 63.0.3239.59 beta

pg <- chrome_read_html("https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-salary-changes?date=2017-11-25")

html_node(pg, "table#stat-table") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() 
## # A tibble: 256 x 7
##    Position          Player Salary         Change `Proj Fantasy Pts` `Avg Fantasy Pts`   Diff
##       <chr>           <chr>  <chr>          <chr>              <dbl>             <chr>  <chr>
##  1       PF      Thon Maker $3,900  +$600 (18.2%)              12.88             13.24  -0.36
##  2       PG DeAndre Liggins $3,500  +$500 (16.7%)               9.68              7.80  +1.88
##  3       PG   Elfrid Payton $6,400  +$700 (12.3%)              32.77             28.63  +4.14
##  4        C   Jahlil Okafor $3,000 -$400 (-11.8%)               1.71             12.63 -10.92
##  5       PF    John Collins $5,200   +$400 (8.3%)              29.65             24.03  +5.63
##  6       SG     Buddy Hield $4,600  -$400 (-8.0%)              17.96             21.84  -3.88
##  7       SF    Aaron Gordon $7,000   +$500 (7.7%)              32.49             36.91  -4.42
##  8       PG    Kemba Walker $7,600  -$600 (-7.3%)              36.27             38.29  -2.02
##  9       PG    Lou Williams $6,600  -$500 (-7.0%)              34.28             30.09  +4.19
## 10       PG       Raul Neto $3,200   +$200 (6.7%)               6.81             10.57  -3.76
## # ... with 246 more rows
```

NOTE: Headless Chrome is having issues on High Sierra due to the new permissions and sandboxing. It works on older macOS systems and Windows/Linux. You just need the right version and the right environment variable set.

Comment: Wow this is awesome, thanks! On a high-level this is how I understand my problem: Without SplashR, my code was calling a website that uses JS tables, and it was trying to scrape before the JS loaded. With SplashR, it waits for the table to load? Also, it currently defaults to DraftKings salaries when the page loads- Is there a way to “click” FanDuel in SplashR? I’ve successfully used Rselenium before but it’s a pain…

Comment: updated with some explanations. The Chrome path + the dev `decapitated` pkg is the easiest path. `splashr` requires a Splash docker image which requires Docker so it's heavyweight-ish just like Selenium. There are online API services like [ScrapingHub](https://scrapinghub.com/) that have limited freemium usage.